# How to return multiple values from an object located in a method in react js

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-native, object

I have been trying to figure this out and look on different sites as well. I am using a method in react to return a value.

It returns the value, however, I want to return not only value information, but the change24h info as well. I dont know how to do this, I think can only return one at a time using this method. I have tried just returning the summary object like

Then in the jsx do stuff like

but that doesnt do. Any other way to do this in this method?

Comment: you can `return { a, b };` then do `const res = aggregateHoldings();` in your render method first, then insert `{ res.a }` and `{ res.b }` (also what you describe will work in principle but needlessly run the entire function twice)